# Recursive relationship too slow

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion, algorithm

Writing:

```
nmax = 10^4;
a = ConstantArray[0, nmax];
b = ConstantArray[0, nmax];
a[[1]] = 1.;
b[[1]] = -4.;
Timing[
 Do[s = Sum[{a[[k]], b[[k]]} b[[n - k]], {k, n - 1}];
    a[[n]] = (2 n + 3) s[[1]] / (2 - 2 n);
    b[[n]] = ((2 n + 3) s[[1]] - (n - 1) s[[2]]) (n + 1) / (n - 1) / (2 n - 1),
    {n, 2, nmax}]; 
 a[[nmax]] / a[[nmax - 1]]]
```

I get:

> {213.328, 24.49613689543326}

where it's evident that the time required is really excessive, so much so that it isn't possible for me to perform simulations with higher `nmax`. I thought `NestList[]` might speed up the calculation process, but I just can't figure out how to manage that `Sum[]`. Some idea? Thank you!

Comment: I get a factor of three by replacing the `SUm` line with `va = Take[a, n - 1];
vb = Take[b, n - 1];
s = {va, vb} . Reverse[vb];`. Possibly more to gain beyond that by using `Compile`.

Comment: Compilation won't work because the numbers are too large ($a_n\sim 24.49^n$) and exceed machine precision capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirming comments of @DanielLichtblau

```
fun[{x_, y_}] := With[{n = Length[x] + 1, r = Reverse[y]},
  Flatten /@ Thread[{{x, y}, {(2 n + 3) #1/(2 - 2 n),
        ((2 n + 3) #1 - (n - 1) #2) (n + 1)/(n - 1)/(2 n - 
            1)} & @@ ({x, y} . r)}]
  ]
h[n_] := #2/#1 & @@ Nest[fun, {{1.}, {-4.}}, n - 1][[1, {-2, -1}]]
```

Comparing with `Do`:
[image]

Comment: @TeM  You are welcome :) I am just providing confirmation of Daniel Lichtblau comment. You can tidy up/improve as you see fit.